# Method to draw rectangle

Tags: java

I created method which returns true if point belongs to Equilateral Triangle. When I want to draw it (coordinative system has point (0,0) in upper left side of screen) I get the fine Equilateral Triangle but it is turned down. Can you tell me why?

```
*
 * calculates m from: y = mx + n 
 */
private int calculateM(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    return (int)((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1));
}

/*
 * calculates n from: y = mx + n 
 */
private int calculateN(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2){
    return (int)(-1*(((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)))*x1+y1);
}

public boolean containsPoint(int x,int y){
    int bx = ax + length;
    int by = ay;
    int cx = ax + (int)(length/2);
    int cy = ay + (int)(length*Math.sqrt(3)/2);
    if( y >= calculateM(ax, ay, bx, by)*x + calculateN(ax, ay, bx, by) &&
    ( y <= calculateM(ax, ay, cx, cy)*x + calculateN(ax, ay, cx, cy)) &&
    ( y <= calculateM(bx, by, cx, cy)*x + calculateN(bx, by, cx, cy))) return true;
    return false;
}
```

The my main idea is create direction between two points and test area belong them. (Ax,Ay) are coordinates of left point A of the triangle AB side of triangle is parallel to x axyis

Comment: are you asking why the triangle gets drawn upside-down? if so, please add your code for drawing

Comment: Yes, that is what I askinkg http://hastebin.com/gesileluhi.java

Comment: In Java (and some other languages), the top left pixel has coordinates(0,0), the coordinate values increase as you go to the right or down. It's similar to reading something in English or another left-to-right language. So you have to mirror your output vertically before printing ( something like 'y = height - y').